# IPod Classic - music gone

Tags: ipod

I turned on my iPod Classic 128 GB and all music content was gone.  I charged it and the Apple symbol appeared and then it turned on with no songs/music at all.
I have not connected to iTunes at all recently.
Please advise.

kristeen

Answer (score 1):

My old classic used to do that kind of trick to me periodically.
I always suspected that the disk format was not particularly robust.

I found the only way to get it going again was to Restore it in iTunes & reload the whole library again - don't plan on being in a hurry, it takes ages.

One thing I did learn over the years was to always leave the lock button **on** [the little slider at the top, slid to show the red dot underneath] all the time unless I actually needed to interact with it.

Also to **never** leave it locked if I was about to connect it to iTunes, otherwise it would hang.

Remembering those two would let me run far longer before it played tricks on me the next time.